# How to disable offline messages in multicast message?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, multicast

Actually I was trying to disable offline messages in my application.

So here is the format of message I get -

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="24@hostname/resource_id" to="25@hostname" type="chat"><addresses xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/address"><address delivered="true" type="to" jid="25@hostname"/></addresses><body>37.444075###-122.267602###24</body><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="hostname" stamp="2017-01-02T14:10:38.480Z">Offline Storage</delay></message>
```

So In my yml file I have removed the mod_offline and restarted the server .Still I am getting these multicast messages , It would be really helpful if somebody can point out the mistake.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the database as well? As discussed here https://www.ejabberd.im/node/3199

Comment: @volatilevar actually I haven't cleared that but these are the new messages I am recieving , checked the timestamp. I also tried to set maximum number of offline messages to 0 , but seems like it isn't working. Any idea?  Basically in a nutshell I only want those archived messages in archive table , don't want those offline messages